# What does "eval TLEN=\${#$1}" mean?

Tags: bash

context is:

```
eval TLEN=\${#$1}
if [ $TLEN -gt 35 ]
then
  ...
fi
```

I guess it might be used to find out the length of $1. I had no idea "\${#$1}" mean.
I had read the bash manual long ago, and forget the most of it, please explain what the notation ${something} mean, I can vaguely recall that that notation is a common pattern.

OK, I found it in the manual. "${#parameter}" is respond for counting the length.

Comment: $1 - the first argument which was passed to your bash script.

Comment: I know, but thanks all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line `eval TLEN=\${#$1}` means: take 1st argument ($1), read from it number of another argument and calculate the length of that another argument.

If your code is called as a script or function `f` like

```
f 2 qwe
```

It will calculate TLEN as 3 because it'll take 1st argument, it points to 2nd argument and the length of the second is 3

Comment: Which part of the expression response for calculating the length?

Answer (score 0):

Since `eval` is a command, its arguments first undergo various expansions, including parameter expansion. Thus,

```
eval TLEN=\${#$1}
```

will expand the value of `$1`, presumably the name of a variable. If `$1` is `foo`, then the shell expands the command to

```
eval TLEN=\${#foo}
```

After quote removal, the command that is actually evaluated is

```
TLEN=${#foo}
```

so `TLEN` is set to the length of the value of the variable whose name is the value of `$1`.